# For $U$ unitary and $U+iI$ hermetic, prove: $U = -iI$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

Let $U$ be a unitary matrix $nxn$ such that $U+iI$ is hermetian.

Prove:

$$
U = -iI
$$

### What i tried (And got stuck...)

If i show that $\forall u \in V$:

$$
<(U+iI)u,u> = 0
$$

Because (U+iI) is hermetic, i will be able to conclude:

$$
(U+iI) = 0 \Rightarrow U = -iI
$$

As needed.

So:

$$
<(U+iI)u,u> = \\ <Uu+iu,u> = \\ <Uu,u> + i<u,u> = \\ <Uu,u>+i||u||^2 =  \\<Uu,u>+i||Tu||^2 = \\ <Uu,u> + i<Uu,Uu> 
$$

But i dont see how can i get to zero here...

Another way that i tried is using hermetic rules:

$$
\forall u,v \in V
<(U+iI)u,u> = <u,(U+iI)u>
$$

I got to: 
$$
2i<v,u> = <v,Uu> - <Uv,u>
$$

I tried to choose $v = u$, but still i dont get too much...

Another try was to look at the norm
$$
||(U+iI)|| = <U+iI,U+iI> 
$$
I whished it will turn out zero, but i got: 
$$
<U+iI,U+iI>  = <U,U> + <I,I>
$$
Now what?

Those are my homework, so better a hint than a solution.

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Do you mean Hermitian rather than hermetic?

Comment: Using `\langle` and `\rangle` looks a lot better than using `<` and `>`: $\langle u,v\rangle$ versus $<u,v>$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the Spectral Theorem? If so, since the matrix $A:=U+iI$ is Hermitian, you know that there exist a diagonal matrix $D=diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ consisting of the eigenvalues for $A$ and an invertible $P$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$. Now try to use/show that

(i) Eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are real and 
(ii) Eigenvalues of unitary matrices have modulus 1,

to conclude that all the $\lambda_i$'s are zero.

Comment: Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of the $A$ you wrote, therefore: $Ax = \lambda x$. $\lambda$ must be a real value - as its Hermetian
Open $A$ we get: $(U+iI)x = \lambda x$ $\Rightarrow Ux = (i-\lambda)x$ but as $\lambda$ real, any real number with $i$ will give a modulo greater than $1$, but $U$ is unitary so $|i-\lambda|$ = 1, therefore it hold only for $\lambda = 0$ Therefore $(U+iI)$ has only zeros as eigenvalues and its unitary diagonaizable as a Hermetian, therefore, its similar to zero matrix, but only the zero matrix similar to zero matrix: $(U+iI) = 0 \Rightarrow U = -iI$

Comment: Yes exactly, that was the idea!

Comment: Thank you alot for helping and guiding.

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that the spectral radius of $U+iI=0$. Since $U+iI$ is Hermitian this is enough prove the result. You will need the facts that spectrum of a unitary operator is contained in the unit circle and the spectrum of a Hermitian operator is contained in the real line.

Note: the spectrum of a matrix is nothing but the set of eigen values and spectral radius is the maximum value of$|\lambda|$ over all eigen values $\lambda$.

Comment: do you think that OP knows all that?

Comment: No i dont, but maybe it will give me a hint. Spectral radius is the largest eigenvalue? and those sentences that you use dont look familiar, im sorry but im still quite a beginner but thanks alot

Comment: @Alon I just explained the terms I had used.

Comment: I start to understand i think lets look at $(U- \lambda I) - \lambda I$ if $\lambda$ is not zero and real, then we get as an eigenvalue of $U$ (i-\lambda) which will be out of the unit cycle, cuz its modulu will be greater than 1, than conclusion - $\lambda = 0$ all the eigenvalues are zero's - so the matrix is similar to the zero matrix - and that is only for the zero matrix namely: $U+iI = 0$ (thanks to Jamie also)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that any element $A$ can be uniquely written as $X+iY$ with $X,Y$ Hermitian (or hermetic, however you like to call them, as long as this means $X=X^*, Y=Y^*$) (take $X=(A+A^*)/2, Y=(A-A^*)/2i)$

Write $U=(U+iI)+i(-I)$. Conclude that $U+U^*=2(U+iI)$ and therefore $U^*=U+2iI$. Multiplying by $U$, we have $U^2+2iU-I=0$. Thus $(U+iI)^2=0$.

Can you see why $U+iI=0$ from here?